# Fastest way to access query a MySql database via .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I am trying to access a very large MySQL table (17.6M rows x 60 columns) in a .NET application and perform some simple analytics within the application.  I have the following code using the .NET MySqlAdapter, where the queryis a simple SELECT ... FROM X query:

```
        using (MySqlConnection client = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            client.Open();
            using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(td, client))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        DoSomething(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am testing this application on the database server itself, to try to eliminate network delays.

Profiling this approach, the total sum of the DoSomething() calls is about 20ms, where the total time spent in the inner while loop is ~8 minutes.

Is there a faster approach to transferring a large amount of data from MySQL to a client application?

Comment: Maybe it's better to do the analytics (if it's simple) in mysql? What does `DoSomething()` do?

Comment: Have you considered reading directly into a `DataSet` ?

Comment: @peterm It involves a lot of transformations based on "runs" of data, which is hard since mysql doesn't support LAG and LEAD.  Even if it could be done via a query, I'm interested in the problem as stated.

Comment: @EralpB I am not sure if I can do that using the native client, though I will experiment with the ODBC client to get a sense of the performance difference between the two.  It will also require some partitioning work since Datatables can hold less than 17M rows.

Comment: @EralpB I did not realize that there are two different DataSet classes being referred to in the MySqlDocs, the native .NET Dataset object and the custom MySqlDataSet class.  The latter looks like it might be designed for this use case, while the former has the really annoying row limitation.  Will investigate.

Comment: Use Linq. Deferred execution saves you.

Comment: Best to do this on the db it self as @peterm pointed out. Since that is not an option, why not consider doing this on a background service (which could easily be written in C#) and store the results, You can have the service running on the db server box to reduce the network traffic (like you are doing now).

Comment: That math is way off.  17 million * 20ms = 5,667 minutes

Comment: @EralpB Really?  You think a DataSet is faster than DataReader?

Comment: @Blam 17M calls took 20ms total.  All the call is doing in my test was shoving fields from the reader into a struct and returning.  The number is very approximate, the way I tested it was doing one run with the line commented out, and one run with it uncommented -- making sure the databases' cache was empty between runs.  I don't know what the "real" number is, but it makes it clear where the problem lies.

Comment: But in real life is that 20ms?  Is DoSomething not really doing to do something?

Comment: @Blam This is going to be sitting in a piece of middleware, it really isn't going to be doing too much more than that in the final application.

Comment: Sorry I am not buying that you are doing 17,000,000 X 60 of simple analysis in 20ms.  I ran a loop on int i from 0 17,000,0000 and assigned it to K and it took 51 ms.  Please send static data to the real analyses 17,000,000 times (no db).   If a line is 1 K you are reading at 35 mb / sec - what is your expectation?

Comment: I just did a test and I read 2 million rows of 4 int32 in 1.7 seconds and over a network so that is a slow read.  I am on MSSQL.

Comment: I was digging some more, and discovered something really surprising.  52.61% of the time being spent in the Read() call is being spent parsing and extracting strings, using the default .NET methods for doing so.  In other words, I have to assume that mysql is sending the data in plaintext, and then MySqlConnector is taking that plaintext and parsing it back to binary data types.  This is a fundamentally flawed approach if you care about performance.